# Matlab find multiple variables in an .slx

Tags: matlab, grep, find, simulink, findstr

I have a master .slx where I have hundreds of models inside and I want to know if some variables are used or not.

I have used grep and findstr in the directory where my whole project is but that is only showing me the files where the variable is declared (.m file) but not where the actual variable is used in the model.

I have tried opening the .slx and do a ctrl+f and yeah, it is telling me where the variable is used but this is not convenient since I have around 100 variables that I need to search for.

Is there a systematically way to do the search throughout the models?

Comment: You probably want to use `find_system` to get all blocks of a specific type, then `get_param` to get the value field of those blocks. From there it should be easy to see which variables are use, essentially programmatically doing the `CTRL`+`F`.